# Invoke COM+ object event handler in C#

Tags: c#, com+

I'm able to invoke a method and get the return value from COM+ and now I would like to invoke an Event in the COM+ and register the events in my application. I had tried a lot of method but failed. Please advise.

```
object obj = this.oType.InvokeMember("OnReadProgress", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this.Com+ObjectName, new object[0]);
```

the above method only working for invoking method and not an events.

Comment: "I had tried a lot of method but failed." - Please show what you tried.

Comment: Why do you want to _invoke_ an event?  You're travelling the wrong way down a one-way road

Comment: Sorry maybe i described it wrongly...I wanted to register an events in C# which react to events from the COM+. From the above codes i'm able to invoke a method and get the return value from the COM+. How can I register an events in C# that consume the events from the COM+ and return the values from the COM+ events on C#